# in Apple OSX how to move the window control buttons to the right side

Tags: macos, operating-systems, gui

In Apple OSX how can I configure (system configuration)
the windows control buttons (Maximize/Minimize/Restore)
to appear always in the right side of the window?

Thx

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: nope--- still using in the annoying side when working with macs... :(

Comment: Had to learn keyboard shortcuts like `cmd+w`, `cmd+m`, `cmd+q`. Easier to use those.

Comment: nop,,, nothing to do with keyboard shortcuts... what I want is to move the icons to the other side..

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is not a way to do this.

Comment: Proving something does not exist is not as simple as proving something exists.I use macOS for some time and I customize all settings before I use my computer and I've never encountered such a setting. After the question I have a little searching and not found a setting nor an application to do it. It does not prove that but there is no known way to do that, at least easy to find.

Comment: Actually, in this case, it's not hard to prove it doesn't exist. Ask in any MacOS user forum and so many Mac users will come down on you for asking, insulting you, and telling you to go find another OS, that it quickly becomes clear no such option exists. :)